# Magento 2 URL to call custom controller not working

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

This is the default magento URL:

```
<base URL>/magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing
```

Now i have a custom controller i want to call this.

```
<base URL>/magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing/test
```

where test is my controller file.
if i even hit the URL directly in browser than also it is going to this

```
<base URL>/magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing
```

Comment: why you need `magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing/test`?

Comment: i have custom payment method on magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing with input field and button, when user hits the button the ajax call automaatically goes to magento2/multishipping/checkout/billing so i added this route with controller.

Answer (score 1):

In **Magento2**, the urls Module are built like this:

> domaine.com/frontnamemodule/controllerfolder/controllerfile

Exemple: `vendor/magento/module-multishipping/Controller/Checkout/Billing.php`

The Url will be : `domaine.com/multishipping/checkout/billing`

Now you want to add `test` at the end of url, `domaine.com/multishipping/checkout/billing/test` ans it is not possible.

You can create your controller like this : `Controller/Checkoutbilling/test.php` and you call it like this : `domaine.com/multishipping/checkoutbilling/test`.

Comment: if i put my controller file inside controller/checkout/billing/test.php?

Comment: Nop, You should not have a sub-folder controller